# Binary relation defined by order isomorphism?

Tags: order-theory

Let's say I have $(E, \leq_{E})$ and $(F, R)$ where $\leq_{E}$ is an order on $E$, and $R$ is some binary relation defined over $F$.

Now if I have a bijection $f : E \to F$ such that,

$$\forall x, y \in E,\: x \leq_{E} y \Leftrightarrow f(x) R f(y)$$

Is it enough to conclude that $R$ defines an order on $F$, as $f$ is an order isomorphism ?

I know it should work, but, can I use the word "order isomorphism" if I have not yet proven $R$ is an order on $F$ ?

It's more a question about an eventual lack or rigour.

Comment: Always go back to the definitions. Does the relation R satisfy each of the conditions needed to be called an order ? Check the conditions one at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that if $E$ has some kind of order on it, then since $f$ is a bijection, then that same kind of order structure will be preserved entirely in $F$. But really, it shouldn't be too hard just to check that the order is preserved, so check it. Then there will be no scruples over calling $f$ an "order isomorphism".

You should verify to yourself as an exercise that the order structure is preserved in $F$. As for whether you include that proof in whatever you are writing up, that is a matter of who your audience is. If this is for a class and you are writing this up for a professor, just include it. If this were for a paper or something where the audience consists of experts in the field, then I would just assert that the order is preserved in $F$.

Comment: It's a well order, the bijection $f$ is between an ordinal and another set, on which I try to define a well order using a choice function on its powerset (minus the empty set).
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, verifying the conditions for a well-order is pretty straight-forward. Take some stuff in $F$, map it to $E$, use the fact that $E$ is a well-order and map the stuff back to $F$ to say the stuff you took in $F$ obeys the well-order.